# Bootstrap switches return "on/off" instead of "true/false"

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, boolean

Bootstrap has massive usage, and lots of people much smarter than me have worked on it, so I'm sure the issue I'm about to point out is a total non issue and I'm just using it wrong, but....

I have a form with a checkbox turned into a switch using `bootstrapSwitch()`

here's my html

```
<div class="bootstrap-switch-square">
   <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="switch" name="Resend" id="Resend" />
</div>
```

And js:

```
$("#Resend").bootstrapSwitch();
```

This produces a neat bootstrap toggle switch on my page. The page posts to an ASP.NET MVC4 controller method, which expects a boolean in the model.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public bool Resend { get; set; }
}
```

When I post this form, my `Resend` boolean is always false. Why? Because bootstrap switch posts a value of `on` rather than `true`.

I don't want to change my model from a boolean to a string, so I'm forced to intercept the post in jquery and change the value of my checkbox to `true` if it's `on`. This seems backwards to me. Surely if `bootstrapSwitch()` is used on a checkbox it should produce `true/false` instead of `on/off`

Am I missing something?

Comment: That's interesting, bootstrapSwitch should return a bool, not on or off. http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/options.html says so atleast.

Comment: Your creating a manual textbox without a value attribute so it posts back the default which is `on`. Either use `@Html.CheckboxFor()` or manually add `value="true"` to your html

Comment: in checkboxes, what gets posted is the value. it gets posted only if the checkbox is checked. otherwise your model property `Resend` in this case takes the default value of its type which is false for a bool. if you look at the webpage source code, the checkbox it uses doesn't have a value. so I think they have override the val method in their code to return "on"

Comment: @Chris, bootstrapSwitch doesn't "return" anything. Its the value of the checkbox which is sent to the server which by default is `on` is its checked (unless a value attribute is provided).

Comment: @roryok please take a look at this sample I created. You can set the value in the code which will get posted instead of "on". http://plnkr.co/edit/0lLclfecpgOwB2sNSLPJ?p=preview

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [HTML specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-value-default-on), the default value for a checkbox is "on" because you have not included a `value` attribute

> default/on
>
> On getting, if the element has a value attribute, it must return that attribute's value; otherwise, **it must return the string "on"**. On setting, it must set the element's value attribute to the new value.

Change you html to

```
<div class="bootstrap-switch-square">
  <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="switch" name="Resend" id="Resend" value="true" />
</div>
```

so that if its checked, a value of `true` will be sent in the form data and correctly bound to your `boolean` property (if unchecked, no value will be sent and the property will be its default (`false`) value

Answer (score 2):

I am just adding my findings to add more values in this question. I have the following code on a razor view

```
<label class="switch">
    @{ var isAssigned = Model?.Any(x => x.Id == group.Id) ?? false; }
    <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle"
           name="AssignedGroups[@index].Assigned"  value="@isAssigned" 
           @(isAssigned ? "checked" : "") />
    <span class="slider"></span>
</label>
```

When the form is posted ModelState was in vaild on it show the following errors

> The value 'value' is not valid for Assigned.

and when i moved the value attribute after the checked attribute it started working

```
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" name="AssignedGroups[@index].Assigned"  
@(isAssigned ? "checked" : "") value="@isAssigned" />
```

From this, I guess the ***order of the value attribute*** is also important. Please corrent me if i am worng.

Answer (score 2):

I needed an actual true or false to be sent, because a validation method wouldn't accept true or nothing. Here is what I did.

```
<input type="hidden" name="myBoolean" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="myBoolean" value="1">
```

this above returns 0

if you check the checbox, and the DOM looks like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="myBoolean" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="myBoolean" value="1" checked>
```

Now the second named element with the same name overwrites the first, and it returns 1.

litteral true/false would work as well