# Checkbox state always passed to controller as null

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

Similar questions have been asked a couple times, but I can't seem to find an answer.

I am `POST`ing some values to a controller action and all the parameters are being passed successfully based off their names, except the bool value of my checkbox. It is always passed as `null`.

Form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddNote", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "function noteAdded();", OnFailure = "alert(xhr.responseText)" }))
{
    <!-- New Note Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="note-add-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="note-add-modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="note-add-modal-Label">Add A Note</h4>
                </div>

              <div class="modal-body">
                  <textarea placeholder="Description..." class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
                  <textarea name="assignTo" id="assign-to" rows="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Assign To..." data-autocomplete-url="@Url.Action("AutoCompleteUsername")"></textarea>
                  <br/>
                  <label id="follow-up-date">Follow-Up Date: <input name="alertDate" class="form-control-date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" id="datepicker" type="text" /></label>
                  <label class="complete-label">Complete:</label>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="complete" name="complete" checked="checked"/>
                  <label for="complete"></label>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="submit" id="note-form-submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

}

The checkbox has the name: `complete`.

Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public void AddNote(string comment, DateTime? alertDate, bool complete, string assignedTo)
    {
        // Unrelated Code
    }
```

I thought you were able to pass the checkbox state to a controller as a bool value through the name. Or it is absolutely necessary to use `@Html.Checkbox`?

Comment: I will comment this because i don't know if it is a good answer, but it happened to me once, it seemed to be the fact that the Ajax sender is not set as classic so by some reason it doesn't understand how to map a checkbox, i did set the value using JavaScript and used a Jquery Ajax Request instead of the Microsoft Provided one. It is just a workaround, because i don't know why does this happens, try to create that checkbox with CheckBoxFor(); You can also try to get the checkbox value as string on your controller.
Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your input, and yeah, I was thinking of just switching to jQuery ajax

Comment: Works fine with jQuery ajax...ditching Microsoft ajax for good

Comment: add value="true" to you input .. `<input type="checkbox" id="complete" name="complete" value="true" checked />`

Comment: Refer also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299849/bootstrap-switches-return-on-off-instead-of-true-false/33300519#33300519)

Comment: Im glad it worked for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binding will check for `value attribute` since there isn't any in your `checkbox` it will always be `false`. One way you can do is to explicitly get `complete` from your `FormCollection` of the current request like following:

```
public void Submit(bool test)
{
    var complete = Request.Form["complete"];
    //complete == null if checkbox was not checked
    //complete == "on" if checkbox was checked
}
```

The other easier way is to just use `@Html.Checkbox("complete")`

Answer (score 0):

If you make a few changes, I think you will have more success. However, if you prefer your controller action to have many arguments instead of a single viewmodel, you may not like my solution.

1. Create a complex viewmodel instead of having several loose arguments. This tends to be easier to maintain over time.

   ```
   public class Note 
   {
     public string Comment {get;set;}
     public DateTime? AlertDate { get; set; }
     public bool Complete { get; set; }
     public string AssignedTo { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Change your Action to take the new viewmodel

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public void AddNote(Note viewModel)
   {
       // Unrelated Code
   }
   ```
3. Set your @model in the CSHTML

   ```
   @model Company.Product.Note
   ```

While `Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Complete)` is the preferred approach, you can still do equivalent HTML manually. However, if the viewmodel changes at all, `Html.CheckBoxFor` will give you a more meaningful error due to name mismatches.

HTH!