# How to change booleanfields using bootstrap switches?

Tags: django

I want to use the switch button on the bootstrap to operate the model called field, but I don't know how to access it.

```py
class NewBlank(models.Model):
    ...
    blank_on_off = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

[image]

If I have the following booleanfield and can I change the booleanfield by cycling the switch as shown in the picture?

Answer (score -1):

From the [HTML specifications](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-input-value-default-on), the default value for a checkbox is "on" because you have not included a value attribute

> default/on
>
> On getting, if the element has a value attribute, it must return that
> attribute's value; otherwise, it must return the string "on". On
> setting, it must set the element's value attribute to the new value.

Change your html to

```
<div class="bootstrap-switch-square">
  <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="switch" name="Resend" id="Resend" value="true" />
</div>
```

so that if its checked, a value of true will be sent in the form data and correctly bound to your boolean property (if unchecked, no value will be sent and the property will be its default (false) value

[originaly answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299849/bootstrap-switches-return-on-off-instead-of-true-false/33300519)

Comment: i don't know what you are taking about. i want that if i click switch on, then booleanfields changes to true.

Comment: if you are not able to follow the explanation at the top, check only the [ change your html to ] part...  if you have the latest CDN of bootstrap the above code will generate a switch, and since the <value> tag is set to true, when the switch is clicked the value of the Boolean field is set to true